# Javascript changing background based on user resolution - code fix?

Tags: javascript, background, resolution

I've been trying to change the background of a school project by finding out what screen resolution the user has, this is my code:

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

 function getResolution(){
    if (width <= 800 && height <= 600) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/800x600.jpg)";
    }
    if (width <= 1024 && height <= 768) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/1024x768.jpg)";
    }
    if (width <= 1152 && height <= 864) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/1152x864.jpg)";
    } 
    if (width <= 1280 && height <= 720) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/1280x720.jpg)";
    } 
    if (width <= 1280 && height <= 768) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/1280x768.jpg)";
    }
    if (width <= 1280 && height <= 800) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/1280x800.jpg)";
    }
    if (width <= 1280 && height <= 960) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/1280x960.jpg)";
    }
    if (width <= 1280 && height <= 1024) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/1280x1024.jpg)";
    }
    if (width <= 1360 && height <= 768) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/1360x768.jpg)";
    } 
    if (width <= 1366 && height <= 768) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/1366x768.jpg)";
    } 
    if (width <= 1440 && height <= 900) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/1440x900.jpg)";
    }
    if (width <= 1600 && height <= 900) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/1600x900.jpg)";
    }
    if (width <= 1680 && height <= 1050) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/1680x1050.jpg)";
    } 
    if (width <= 1920 && height <= 1080) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/bkg.jpg)";
    }
 }
```

For some reason it always jumps to the last if structure, the 1920x1080 one, on any resolution.

I think it's the basic structure of how I did it, maybe it should be if else {}, it does work for 1920x1080p though.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you do not wish to use css for this?

Comment: Can css approach what I want to achieve? My container has a specific width, I've added logos to the left and right of my container. On any resolution lower than 1920x1080, the container stretches over the logos when approached with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should use CSS media queries for this.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) , screen and (max-height: 600px) {
    background-image:url("Images/ResBackgrounds/800x600.jpg");
}
```

etc

Your if statements are ALL triggering, so since almost every screen resolution is under 1920x1080, the final statement will trigger every time.

Comment: So this basically does the same thing as what I did, but it checks for actual resoultion rather than the window settings? What happens if I resize?

Comment: That's what media queries are for!

Comment: This specific code is not working for me for some reason:

`@media screen and (max-width: 1920px) , screen and (max-height: 1080px) {
background-image:url("Images/ResBackgrounds/bkg.jpg");
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `if else` so that once a condition is found that matches, it stops checking the rest of the `if` statements.

Comment: Yeah that worked, I'm gnna look into these media queries

Answer (score 0):

You are not testing for the screen resolution, but the size of the browser window.
I would use CSS media queries to do this:

css code:

```
    @media screen and (min-width : 966px) { 
        body { backgound-image: url('pix/someimage1.png')
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 966px) and (min-width: 800px){ 
        body { backgound-image: url('pix/someimage2.png')
    }
```

etc.. (make more rules)

This way the background will also be updated when the window resizes, you don't have to listen for window resize events.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use range for the screen resolution, not only less or equal.

```
if (width <= 800 && height <= 600) {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/800x600.jpg)";
}
else if (width >= 1024 && width < 1152 && height >= 768 && height < 864) {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url(Images/ResBackgrounds/1024x768.jpg)";
} ...
```

Something like that. But it is not efficient.

Comment: This did fix my problem, but I'm going to look into these media queries as those seem more efficient indeed.. I'm quite new to this